# What is wrong with next jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

can you help me why it returns error.

part of code /publications/deleteItem/' + valueClicked works ok, i checked (proper item is properly deleted).

```
var valueClicked = 123456;
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/publications/deleteItem/' + valueClicked, // 100% works!
    success: function(xml) {
        alert('602!');
    }, 
    error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown); // throwns undefined?!
    }

});
```

so, alert('602!') never exetutes...

Comment: What response are you getting from the server?

Comment: A slight correction to the answers below, the only statuses jQuery accepts (at the time of this comment) are 200-299, 304, 1223 and 0 (which opera gives for a 304).  301/302 will be transparently followed by the XmlHttpRequest, so jQuery doesn't see *those*, it sees whatever the destination code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open up the net panel in firebug and look at the response codes. successful response codes are 2xx or 3xx.

also try changing the success and error callbacks as follows and report back what you get.

```
success:function(data, status, xml) {
    alert(status);
},
error:function(data, status, xml) {
    alert(status);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with this jQuery code. The server simply didn't return a HTTP 2nn or 3nn response, but a 4nn or 5nn response. This will cause the error handler being invoked instead of the success handler.

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s [*Net*](http://getfirebug.com/network) panel to check the response headers and the status.

Comment: can i somehow make that it always return 'success'?

Comment: You can do that by ensuring that the HTTP response status is 2nn or 3nn. A normal success response code is 200. This is the default when your PHP code runs without errors/dies/wrong-redirects/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to create a REST interface you should test direct calls for what do you want to do in the first place.

Let's imagine you domain is: http://www.mydomain.com

Try to call http://www.mydomain.com/publications/deleteItem/123456 and see what is returned from the server. The most probably your server is doing a redirect or outputting some error,and that's the source of your problem.